# Socket hangup error in VercelCLI Nextjs deploy

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my next.js frontend using Vercel CLI but I'm getting an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xpIk.png)

How to fix this?
version Vercel CLI 27.1.2

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem documented also on their github issue page, you can deploy ur project on vercel by uploading ur project on github (also in a private repository) and then going on https://vercel.com/ and linking it to your github repository, as there is not a good solution to the issue, people stated that after a few days it started working again. You may want to try go on [this link](https://api.vercel.com/v12/deployments/test) and see if it gives you any response, if it doesen't you might be rate limited or your ip is blocked for some reason.